# DynamoDB GSI table replication when partition key is same as the main table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Case 1) When we create a GSI with a partition key different from the main table's partition key, the dynamo replicates the data into another table under the hood. Which is understood.
Case 2) What if I create a GSI with the same partition key as the main table's PK but just with a different sort key? Will it replicate the data the same way as in Case 1? This situation sounds similar to an LSI because they also share the partition key with the main table. If I created an LSI instead, would it save me any data replication and hence the cost associated with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it replicates the same as Case 1. In general people should use GSIs unless they absolutely require LSIs.

Pros of an LSI:

- Enables strongly consistent reads out of the index

Cons of an LSI:

- Cannot be added or deleted after table creation
- Prevents an item collection (items having the same PK) from growing beyond 10 GB (because to maintain strong reads the item collection has to be co-located)
- Prevents adaptive capacity from isolating hot items in the item collection across different partitions (again, due to the need to be co-located)
- Increases the likelihood of a hot partition because the base table write and LSI writes always go to the same partition, limiting write throughput to that partition (whereas a GSI has its own write capacity)

It's not actually true to say LSIs don't cost extra. They still consume write capacity, just out of the base table's allotment.

Answer (score -1):

Any GSI regardless of the key is a separate table you pay extra for.

An LSI doesn't cost <s>any extra</s> quite as much as a GSI; especially if using a provision table.  Additionally, an LSI has strongly consistent reads available just like the base table.  GSI only offer eventually consistent reads.

However, the downside to using an LSI instead of a GSI, is that a table with an LSI is limited to a partition size of 10GB.

In other words, if you try to add data above 10GB in a table with the same partition (aka hash) key, if there's any LSIs it will fail.

[If there are no LSIs, then it will succeed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.ItemCollections.SizeLimit).

> ***Item collection size limit***
> The maximum size of any item collection for
> a table which has one or more local secondary indexes is 10 GB. This
> does not apply to item collections in tables without local secondary
> indexes, and also does not apply to item collections in global
> secondary indexes. Only tables that have one or more local secondary
> indexes are affected.

So depending on your data, it might behoove you to pay for the GSI even if an LSI would work instead.

Comment: FYI: LSIs still incur write costs, just allocated to the base table.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.StorageConsiderations. According to this link, "Your AWS account is charged for storage of the item in the base table and also for storage of attributes in any local secondary indexes on that table." So looks like LSI also has replication and extra storage costs same or at least similar to GSI. I am not sure why so many people think LSI doesn't incur extra costs.

Comment: @Naeem Thanks for the correction.   I updated the answer around LSI costs.